# HTML to doc using php default save as web document (.html) issue

Tags: php

I have created HTML to Doc using php and header. It creates proper doc file what I want but when I download that doc file and click on SAVE AS its default type as webpage( .html).

Here is my code I am using to create doc file.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/msword;charset=iso-8859-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=IEP-Annual-Goals.doc');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$html='<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-8" />
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 9">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 9">

<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>
<w:Save>.doc</w:Save>
<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>';
// and main html block

//Then simply echo html to directly download doc file.
echo $html;
```

When I open doc file and save as, Its default type is web document(.html) but I need it as document(.doc) file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080943/download-php-generated-webpage-as-html-file Refer this for more info.

Comment: I want to save file as doc file. and when I open that file and click on save as then default type is .html but I want it as .doc.

Comment: @BhaveshMalaviya  you use html & xml both to convert in doc file?

Comment: If I remove that xml code then also it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your doing this all wrong there is already phpword

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Which'll create doc files for you.

Comment: I already tried phpword but for that I need to recreate entire structure of file because in phpword my existing html not showing properly.

Comment: It has a phpword has a html to doc function.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_26_Html.php
In the past I also used the phpword replace function so have 'replace' areas that you can replace with your variables. That might be good enough for you.